# Node JS close a read stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm stuck with closing a read stream. I'm using csv-parser module to read data from a CSV file, do some processing and write data to MongoDB. Everything is working except I'm unable to exit my program. It just waits around and I've to force quit it. How can I finish its execution?

```
const main = () => {
  const records = [];

  fs.readdir(dataPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log("Failed to read. ", err);
    else {
      fs.createReadStream(`${dataPath}/${files[0]}`)
        .pipe(csv({ skipLines: 7, mapHeaders: ({ header, index }) => _.camelCase(header) }))
        .on("data", data => records.push(data))
        .on("end", async () => await saveToDB(getSysInfo(files[0]), records));
    }
  });
};

main();
```

I tried adding a `.on("close")` event after end but that doesn't help either.

Comment: If you comment out all of the interaction with MongoDB, does it complete normally?

Comment: no, it doesn't end. I tried removing call to mongodb, still waits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an enhancement on your answer that adds error handling for the readStream and for the two `await` operations so if there are any errors your program can still end in a controlled fashion and properly close the database:

```
const getRecordsFromFile = fileName => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rows = [];
    fs.createReadStream(fileName)
      .pipe(csv({ skipLines: 7, mapHeaders: ({ header, index }) => _.camelCase(header) }))
      .on("data", row => rows.push(row))
      .on("end", () => resolve(rows));
      .on("error", reject);                      // <==
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dataPath);

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const records = await getRecordsFromFile(`${dataPath}/${files[i]}`);
      await loadRecordsToDB(getSysInfo(files[i]), records);
    }
  } catch(e) {                                             // <==
      console.log(e);                                      // <==
  } finally {                                              // <==
      // make sure we always close the connection
      mongoose.connection.close();
  }
};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

**For CLI you have to close mongodb connection/ using db.close() u can close.**

**Syntax:**

```
// any other clean ups
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose connection disconnected');
    });
```

**Refactored code:**

```
const util = require("util");
const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const readCSV = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let records = [];
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(
        csv({
          skipLines: 7,
          mapHeaders: ({ header, index }) => _.camelCase(header)
        })
      )
      .on("data", data => {
        records.push(data);
      })
      .on("error", error => {
        rej(data);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        res(records);
      });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  try {
    const files = await readDir(dataPath);
    await Promise.all(
      files.map(file => {
        return readCSV(`${dataPath}/${file}`) // read csv
          .then(csv => saveToDB(getSysInfo(file), csv)); // save in db
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    db.close(); // close mongo db
  }
};
main();
```

Comment: thanks I tried this. I put the destroy call inside end event. Still no luck. Hanging around after it inserted into Mongo

Comment: try to timeout mongo save, may be issue with mongo.! of the data is wrong. Try to catch error white save. `try-catch.`

Comment: no error is thrown during insertion. All records are inserted into DB

Comment: I figured out the problem. Its not with the ```fs.createReadStream```. it is with underlying MongoDB connection itself. I opened the connection when program starts and it is still alive. I've to close out the connection to exit the program. I'm figuring out where to put the close method

Comment: @kunaguvarun - To finish up this question, I'd suggest you post your own answer that explains what the problem was.  After enough time has passed, you can even accept your own answer.

Comment: @jfriend00. I did. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This answer puts `readStream.destroy()` in the wrong place.  If the stream was even the problem (which it turns out it isn't as the stream auto-closes), you would put the destroy in the `end` event.  This would kill the stream after the first `data` event.

Comment: As suggested, i have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. The problem is with underlying MongoDB connection itself. There is nothing wrong with the stream. After I read records from file, insert them to DB and after all the records from all the files are read and inserted, I close out the underlying connection to end the program.

```
const getRecordsFromFile = fileName => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const rows = [];
    fs.createReadStream(fileName)
      .pipe(csv({ skipLines: 7, mapHeaders: ({ header, index }) => _.camelCase(header) }))
      .on("data", row => rows.push(row))
      .on("end", () => resolve(rows));
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dataPath);

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const records = await getRecordsFromFile(`${dataPath}/${files[i]}`);
    await loadRecordsToDB(getSysInfo(files[i]), records);
  }
  mongoose.connection.close();
};

main();
```

Comment: I would suggest adding an `error` event handler to your stream and a `try/finally` block to catch errors on either of the `await` calls.